# Capture mouse movement and export to image [code | app]

Tags: c#, drawing, capture

To get more in depth information about the usage of WinForm or Webapplications I want to capture mouse-movement and click information. It would be perfect if this could be rendered to an image.

The result would be something like this:

[image: Google: capture display "mouse movement" app to image]

The question is how does one start with creating an app like this?

- How do I receive mousemovements and clicks when its a process from another application?
- How convert mousemovements to an image?

(Anyone know if there is a opensource of free/cheap app which can do this)

[IOGraphica](http://iographica.com/) is able to do this, but it is in Java and it is free, but not open source.

Comment: It'd be interesting to render this over a screenshot of the application aswell.

Comment: Indeed, will also add a capture as background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something which you could run externally and track mouse movement and clicks, you might find this mouse/keyboard hooking project over at codeproject.com useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalmousekeyboardlib.aspx

There's a sample application and a hooking lib with full source.  It'd be a starting point to use in your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to **capture** any **mouse movement/click** of your windows and store it in a collection. When you **finished recording** - try to **draw your image**. I would recommend looking for *"c# capture mouse"* or *"mouse hook"* in google.  Some time ago I did this for getting a keyboard hook. You may have a look at [*Processing Global Mouse Events*](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

In terms of code this may help:

```
Dictionary<Point, MouseEventInfo> dict = new Dictionary<Point, MouseEventInfo>();

/// see given link to find the correct way to get this kind of event
public void mouse_event(....)
{
   /// get mouse coordinates

   /// create point struct

   /// check if point exists in DICT

   /// no - add new MouseEventInfo at Point

   /// yes - access MouseEventInfo object and increase a value according to the event

}

public void onFinished()
{
     /// create new bitmap/image - width/height according to your screen resultion

     /// iterate through all MouseEventInfo objects and draw any information

}

/// stores mouse event info for a point
class MouseEventInfo
{
      Point p;
      int moved=0;
      int clicked=0;
      int doubleClicked=0;
}
```

I know this is just a piece of pseudoCode - anyway - I hope this may help you! Ah - keep in mind that any kind of hook (keyboard, mouse or anything else) **may result in a virus alert** of your antiVir.

hth